# Check for user interaction in the workspace

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to make what I think is a basic script in Blender 2.9.1; however, for this to work I need to check if the user performs any form of interaction in the current workspace (essentially if they're idle or not). How can I go about performing this check? I've looked through the API documentation, but I haven't been able to find anything that does this. The only real approach to this I can think of would be to go through all operators and add a check to see if they're performed perhaps.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

For your special case I would use a mix out of modal operator and the depsgraph_update handler.

The modal operator doesn't run when the other operators run. E.g. move operator.
Then the depsgraph_update handler run, because the user make important changes to the scene. So if one of them runs the user interact with blender.

Some cases that are not caught: moving nodes, moving the frame slider (only found these 2)
For these case you maybe could use an event to check if the mouse was pressed and then released or if a key was pressed which starts the moving.